# Append limit 5 times only jquery .append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen similar questions with answers here but nothing could fix my issue. So i am asking it here again.

With jquery i want users to add input field five times only , i used .append which is working fine but its adding unlimited times.

```
$("#add-cert").click(function(){
        var $addinput = $("<div class='row'><div class='small-6 columns'><label class='right inline'>Enter Your Certificate</label></div><div class='small-6 columns'><input type='text'></div></div>");

        $("i").append($addinput);

        });
```

Please provide fix , i am new to jquery. I have tried following code too but with this code .append stops working:

```
$("#add-cert").click(function(){
        var $addinput = $("<div class='row'><div class='small-6 columns'><label class='right inline'>Enter Your Certificate</label></div><div class='small-6 columns'><input type='text' name='manual-cert'></div></div>");

        var num = $("input[name='manual-cert']").length;

        if(num > 5){
        $("i").append($addinput);
        }
        });
```

Comment: Don't give different inputs the same name.

Comment: You're soo close. Just change `if(num > 5)` to `if(num < 5)` (if num is less than 5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var maxAppend = 0;
$("#add-cert").click(function(){
    if (maxAppend >= 5) return;

    var addinput = $(
        "<div class='row'><div class='small-6 columns'>"+
        "<label class='right inline'>Enter Your Certificate</label></div>"+
        "<div class='small-6 columns'><input type='text'></div></div>");
    maxAppend++;

    $("i").append(addinput);
});
```

Comment: There's no benefit to wrapping `addInput` in `$()`. A string works just fine. Great answer, though!

Comment: @David-SkyMesh Your code worked thanks alot. I am new but i will remember this. Thanks everyone for reading and answering. 1 question why did you add "+" ?

Comment: In the `addinput` construction? To make it fit into the stackoverflow display on narrow screens :-) While the display box does scroll, sometimes that's hard to do on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

Well a new idea to manage this is just remove the click handler after appending 5 elements.

```
var count = 1;

$("#add-cert").click(function(){
    if(count < 5) {
        var $addinput = $("<div class='row'><div class='small-6 columns'><label class='right inline'>Enter Your Certificate</label></div><div class='small-6 columns'><input type='text'></div></div>");

        $("i").append($addinput);

        count++;
    }
  else{
    $("#add-cert").off("click");   //remove click listener. 
 }
});
```

Comment: code is copied from the previous answer. Just added my one else statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

$("#add-cert").click(function(){
    if(count < 5) {
        var $addinput = $("<div class='row'><div class='small-6 columns'><label class='right inline'>Enter Your Certificate</label></div><div class='small-6 columns'><input type='text'></div></div>");

        $("i").append($addinput);

        count++;
    }
});
```